# How do I get detailed dvd formatting info in OS X?

Tags: macos, formatting, dvd-burning, fedora-15

The GUI in OS X does not provide enough detail about my HFS+ formatted DVDs. I can't get pdisk -l to tell me anything useful.

I have two DVD backups made and formatted in "HFS+". I can only get one to mount in Fedora 15. How can to determine what the differences are between the two disks? I'm sure one was made with Disj Utility and the other with a third party app.

Comment: did you try the command-line utility `diskutil`?

Comment: That's what I wanted +1, or plus a zillion if you post as answer. And certainly deserve it if you have the OS X equivalent of [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html).

Comment: most commands in the linked page work on Mac as well (since it is also a Unix). If certain tools are missing, try [fink](http://finkproject.org/) or [macports](http://www.macports.org/) to install additional software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command-line version of Disk Utility, [`diskutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8) should provide the functionality you use.

To view a list of partitions, type

```
$ diskutil list
```

to get additional information on a certain disk (e.g. disk1), type

```
$ diskutil disk1
```

if you are using [CoreStorage](http://blog.fosketts.net/2011/08/04/mac-osx-lion-corestorage-volume-manager/) (in OS X 10.7 and above), you can also query the CoreStorage information with

```
$ diskutil corestorage list
$ diskutil corestorage info disk1
```